# ¿Cómo traducir o expresar en español la palabra "tuple" que se usa en Python?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática, inglés

¿Cómo traducir o expresar en español la palabra *"tuple"* que se usa en el lenguaje de programación Python? Ya que en algunos documentos de referencia de Python, redactados en español, usan la palabra "tupla" y ésta palabra no se encuentra en el Diccionario de la RAE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una "tupla" es un tipo de dato que permite agrupar en una sola unidad diversas variables, normalmente de tipos distintos (registros). Así se trata de una variable que es un conjunto de variables (Un objeto puede contener internamente otros objetos). Todos los datos pueden agruparse en el interior de una "tupla" y varias "tuplas" de este tipo pueden albergar un número ilimitado de información que posteriormente puede ser tratada. Cada elemento de la "tupla" se llama campo y la "tupla" se define como una función finita que mapea (asocia unívocamente), nombres con algunos valores.

Las "tuplas" encuentran razón en el estudio de las bases de datos, sobre todo en el campo del cálculo relacional ya que proporcionan una notación básica para formular la definición de la relación en términos de las relaciones de la base de datos.

---

**NOMBRE TUPLA**

En este caso mejor saber de donde procede el término "Tupla" que buscar un nombre para él, ya que puede ser perfectamente válido, una vez entendido.

---

Ideas Generales

El término "tupla", es en sí, una colección ordenada de objetos, llamados "componentes", "elementos" o "términos", la idea se generó a partir de la extensión de la propia secuencia.  Para algunos, las "tuplas", son conocidas como tipos de registro.

Una n -tupla es una secuencia (o lista ordenada) de n elementos, donde n es un número entero no negativo . Solo hay una tupla 0, denominada tupla vacía . Una n -tupla se define inductivamente usando la construcción de un par ordenado.

*Los matemáticos suelen escribir "tuplas" enumerando los elementos entre paréntesis " ( ) " y separados por comas; por ejemplo, (2, 7, 4, 1, 7) denota una tupla de 5*.

- En Inglés - (**Tuple**) El término se originó como consecuencia de la misma secuencia; single, couple/double, triple, quadruple, quin**tuple**, sex**tuple**, sep**tuple**, oc**tuple**, ..., n‑**tuple**.
- En Español - (**Tupla**) la secuencia generada se tomó en su forma femenina;  dupla, tripla, cuádrupla, quín**tupla**, séx**tupla** ... llegando a **n-tupla**. Una tupla de longitud "n" se describe generalmente como una n-**tupla**. Una 2-tupla, por ejemplo, se denomina un par o dupla; una 3-**tupla** una tripla.
- En Francés es "uplet"

Aunque los usos tratan "‑uple" como el sufijo, sin embargo, el sufijo original era "‑ple" como en "triple" (tres veces) o "decuple" (diez veces). Esto se origina en el latín medieval "plus" (que significa "más") relacionado con el griego "-πλοῦς", que reemplazó al tardío "-plex" (que significa "doblado"), como en "dúplex", (doble - dos veces más), (triple - tres veces más).

- Bases de datos relacionales pueden identificar formalmente sus filas (registros) como "tuplas" - πλοῦς (encierran más, rico, abundante en registros). "tuplas" (lleno de registros, secuencias y variables mul-tiples, (mul-tuples), (multiplicar por)).
- "Tuple/s" o "Tupla/s", basados solo en el nombre, harían referencia general a un tipo de contenedor que agrupa en su interior, variables, extensiones de secuencias y distintos elementos o tipos de registros.

---

Comment: Excelente respuesta @Diego, no deja lugar a dudas. Se agradece el compartir este conocimiento.

Answer (score 6):

¡Hola!

Aunque la palabra **tupla** no aparezca en la RAE, es de uso extendido en el ámbito científico (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupla).

Así pues, si tu objetivo es dirigirte a un ámbito científico, no creo que haya ningún problema en la comprensión de esta palabra. En cualquier caso, bastaría definir una vez lo que se entiende por tupla y después usarla de forma natural.

Answer (score 4):

La propia documentación de Python en castellano usa el término *tupla*.

Véase por ejemplo en el manual, en [5. Estructuras de datos -> 5.3. **Tuplas** y secuencias](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).